# Include .cpp files in CMakeLists to be able to switch from .h to .cpp

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I am new to qtCreator and cmake. I have a project with a CMakeLists.txt which is working correctly.

I have a file main.cpp which contains the

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...
}
```

At the top of this file I have several includes like:

```
...
#include <visp/vpImageIo.h>
#include <visp/vpPixelMeterConversion.h>
#include <visp/vpPose.h>
...
```

They are working correctly thanks to the CMakeLists.txt file which is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( opencv_apriltag2_flea )

set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set( CMAKE_BUILD_DIRECTORY "/home/fschiano/Repositories/apriltag2/example")

#DEBUG
message( "CMAKE_BUILD_DIRECTORY=${CMAKE_BUILD_DIRECTORY}")

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package(VISP REQUIRED)

include_directories("/home/fschiano/Repositories/apriltag2")
include_directories("/home/fschiano/Repositories/apriltag2/common")
include_directories("usr/local")
include_directories("/home/fschiano/Repositories/visp/visp/modules/vision/src")
find_library(FLYCAPTURE2 flycapture)
add_executable( opencvDemo opencv_demo.cc )

include_directories(${VISP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#DEBUG
message( "VISP_INCLUDE_DIRS=${VISP_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message( "VISP_LIBRARIES=${VISP_LIBRARIES}")

# Needed libraries
set (EXTRA_LIBS apriltag flycapture ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${VISP_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries( opencvDemo ${EXTRA_LIBS} )
```

The problem is the following. 
If I do :

```
vpPose pose; // Create an istance of vpPose
```

and then

```
point[i].set_x(x);
point[i].set_y(y);
pose.addPoint(point[i]);
```

where `point` has been declared before.

Everything works but, in QTCreator, I am not able to look at the implementation of the function `addPoint()`. This is the same for every function I have in my code which is related to visp.

In my opinion is because I am using this software (ViSP) as an external library and therefore qtCreator is looking only at the compiled version of the file related to it and it has no knowledge about where to search for the .cpp files.

I think I need to change something in the CMakeLists.txt file.

I tried by including the line:

```
include_directories("/home/fschiano/Repositories/visp/visp/modules/vision/src")
```

Where my .cpp file is. But it is not working.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think this a Qt Creator issue but rather what you are trying to do. Accessing the implementation of a given function, class etc. can be done in two ways (as far as I know) - you bundle the source files in your project (you can list these in your `CMakeLists.txt` either manually or using `file()` for example which grabs files for you based on a pattern) or access the repsective symbols during debugging if the library that you are linking against provides the debug info for this task (release builds strip the binary of all debug info hence symbols cannot be "viewed").

Comment: If you bundle the sources you don't need to actually compile the library. It's just for making sure that `cmake` (and Qt Creator respectively) can see these. Btw `include_directories()` is **for include files only** as both the name and the `cmake` docs state: `Add the given directories to those the compiler uses to search for include files`. You can't use it to add source files to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try to do what you said in the first comment and let you know.

Comment: The thing is, you are linking against an existing library by using `find_package(VISP REQUIRED)` and linking to it with `target_link_libraries` so cmake really has no concept of what source files were build into that library.

Comment: @kiki yeah, I understood this. At the end the behavior that I have should be like that. It makes sense, but it also means that if I want to look at the implementation I should go everytime *manually* in the specific function.

Comment: Ok. I think I understood a bit more how I could solve my problem. It is not a solution but more a workaround to not make my CMakeLists.txt dirty.

In qtCreator I just *Load* the ViSP project and in this way I will have all the ViSP related files in Qt.

Comment: Yeah, this sound right. Actually I filed a bug report 1-2 weeks ago for this behaviour. :D Omho it's not normal for multiple projects in the session to interact with each other in such an implicit way.